# Caching $(this) in jQuery is a best practice?

Tags: jquery, caching, this

We all know it's good to cache calls to the DOM, so instead of calling $('#someElement') more times, just save it to a var $someElement and use that.

But is it the same when using $(this) inside an event listener for example?
Should $(this) be cached?

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect it entirely depends on what the usage pattern is for `$(this)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time you call `$(this)` or `$(selector)` it is a function call to create a new jQuery object... so if you have already created it once, caching will save calling a function to create the same object again

Answer (score 7):

If you call `$(this)` multiple times, it is better to do something like `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: Is there performance gain or is it just for saving characters (2 per usage)?

Comment: @Tx3 No, it is not just for saving characters, it is saving function calls. You did function call every time when you do `$(this)`.

Comment: sure, I was just thinking what kind of operation it is doing when it does the "wrapping". Anyway, I have been using it like you suggested, so it was just curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the same element later in the event function, yes. Outside of the function it doesn't make any sense to do so because the value of `this` will have changed.